# Index related table using Haystack/Whoosh

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

How can I index a related table:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Class FooImg(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/', default = 'img/no-img.jpg',
                              verbose_name='Image', )
   foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to index FooImg, so that I can get the images associated with Foo.

I have already indexed Foo, and it works perfectly fine, it returns expected result. So in my template I have:

```
{% for r in foo_search %}
   {{ r.object.name | slice:":18" }}
{% endfor %}
```

The above works, but I can't figure out how I can get the associated FooImg objects?

Looking for direction,

Comment: Do you need to search for the image or just get the image from the object?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid The search result returns all relevant foo objects, but I can't figure out how to get the images associated with each object. For example, if I had an image field in foo, then I would be able to {{ r.object.image.url }} for each object within the for loop, I don't know how to do it in the above scenario.

Comment: Can an object can have more than one image?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid yes, if it only had one image, then I would have chosen the imagefield solution rather than an image class.

Comment: Sorry, had to ask =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `related_name` to your `fk`:

```
foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name='images')
```

Then get the images and do what you need with them, probably loop over them:

```
obj.images.all()
```

Comment: Welp, you're right about it being straight forward. Thanks alot, it worked :)

Comment: Everything is easy once you know how to do it! =)