# Django Best Practices? image upload

Tags: django, django-models

Is it a good idea to use contenttypes in my project ?, I have a user model, post and event, all three have in common an image field.

I just start with django and I prefer that this does not cause me problems later.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based but if it's only one image per instance just add an image field to each of the models. If there will be multiple images per instance then consider using a generic relation (ie. contenttypes).

Comment: I'd avoid using content types. You could make a `MyAppImage` class and give the other models a `ForeignKey` to an object if they all share it.

Comment: Creating an alternative class for images makes it difficult to index in Haystacks etc.. for example you query "abc", all the objects will be return with the keyword, but how would you get the Images associated with each object? It wouldn't be very straight forward.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you

Comment: @almostabeginner I had not thought of that, thank you

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid thank you

Comment: @almostabeginner it is extremely straight forward...

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid I'm having some trouble, please do help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004561/index-related-table-using-haystack-whoosh